# using lzma compression from python and blocking until compression is done

Tags: python, lzma

I am using lzma to compress a file from python. After the compression I want to move the file to another location. Problem is that when I call the subprocess.Popen with arguements for lzma, it returns immediately without waiting for the compression to finish and I end up moving partial file.

My Code:

```
def CheckOutputLzma(args, outfile, cwd=None, print_stdout=False, print_stderr=True,
            fail_if_stderr=False):
    if not cwd:
        cwd = os.getcwd()

    child = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=outfile, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=cwd)
    stdout, stderr = child.communicate()

    if child.returncode or (stderr and fail_if_stderr):
        raise CalledProcessError(cwd, args, stdout + stderr)

    if print_stdout:
        sys.stdout.write(stdout)
    if print_stderr:
        sys.stderr.write(stderr)

        return stdout


def CompressLibrary(inputFile , library , outputPath):

    if os.path.isfile(outputPath+"/"+library+ ".lzma"):
        os.remove(outputPath+"/"+library+ ".lzma")

    command = (['lzma'] + ['-5'] + ['-c'] + [inputFile])

    with open(outputPath+"/"+library+ ".lzma","wb") as out:
        CheckOutputLzma(command, out)

#Wait until the lzma is complete

check_command = (['lzma'] + ['-t'] + [outputPath+"/"+library+ ".lzma"])

while True:
    #stdout = build_utils.CheckOutput(check_command, None, True, True)
    stdout = subprocess.check_output(check_command)
    print("STDOUT : " + stdout)
    break

    if (not stdout):
       break
```

Comment: Try to use the [lzma](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/lzma.html) module instead.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.6 and do not have the lzma module. Problem is that I cannot change the Python version or introduce new modules as I am a part of a big project and its better if the changes I do have minimum impact on others.